# Does anybody know how to make this text style?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, text, typography

Anybody can help me how to make this text style that I circled? Thank you so much

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This particular style can be rendered without using shadows or other special rendering features by by making three copies of the set type and then stacking them on top of each other, each one offset from the one above it, and the middle one set to the "paper color."

If done as black and white, then it can easily be used as a stencil or mask.

Photoshop:

[image]

Word:

[image]

Comment: Any software that does type and allows for positioning. This can also be achieved using paper cutouts.

Answer (score 0):

It is vintage retro style. Which i can achive using this css style

text-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #eee, 7px 7px 0px #707070;

In Photoshop:
Create a duplicate layer of text, move it below the original text layer.change the color of this new created second layer.
move this little bit left and down.
Also give black drop-shadow to original text layer

Some tutorials to get it in photoshop and illistrator 
shown after step 17.
http://abduzeedo.com/vintage-typography-experiment-illustrator-and-photoshop

Comment: Hi Rajnikant Sharma, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!